# Hyperlink function in Excel doesn't work for long file path

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to use the hyperlink function in Excel to automatically create links to file paths that are longer than 255 characters.

From 256 characters, I receive a `#VALUE` error. I have tried braking the file path in various cells (all less than 255 characters) and then concatenate back in the hyperlink formula (`=HYPERLINK(E2&F2&G2&H2,"Click Here"`). but it still doesn't work.

Any suggestions as to what I can do, to have this work?

Comment: Use the other hyperlink function? i.e. Right click on cell & select hyperlink. And/or then link to that link with the =HYPERLINK() function.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Philippe, but im looking for a solution that would be automatic, in the sense that i shouldn't have to manually create the link. When i try making the link manually (right click on cell; select link; create link on the link window) it works fine. But i have to make links for 1000s of cells, can't do it this way